# draw segments on an image in Matlab given a set of correspondences

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a set of correspondences between points in two different images, and I want to plot them as lines in an image obtained concatenating the two original images, in order to show those correspondences.
I have done the following:

```
function plotInliers(im1, im2, locs1, locs2, corr, inliers)
    l1 = locs1(:, 1:2);
    l1 = l1(corr(:, 1), :);
    l2 = locs2(:, 1:2);
    l2 = l2(corr(:, 2), :);
    l2 = l2 + repmat([0 size(im1, 2)], size(l2, 1), 1);
    im = horzcat(im1, im2);
    figure
    imshow(im)
    hold on

    % plot the correspondences: green inliers, red outliers 
    for ii = 1:size(corr, 1)
        hold on
        % Check if it is an inlier
        if any(ii==inliers), color = 'g'; else color = 'r'; end

        plot([l1(ii, 1) l1(11, 2)], [l2(ii, 1) l2(ii, 2)], ... 
             'Color', color, 'LineWidth', 1)

    end
    hold off

end
```

**im1/im2** are the two images, **locs1/locs2** are the significative points in the images, **corr** is the array containing the correspondences between indexes.

However, the result is absolutely wrong, in a sense that the indexes seems to be completely wrong. The two images have both this size: [388 517 3]

I also tried to plot a single line on the image

```
line([1 1], [300 800])
```

but, again, the result is wrong, in a sense that the lines does not start on the first pixel of the first image and does not ends up on the second one. The result that I get is that this line starts from (more or less) pixel [1 300] and the line goes down straight.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed up your coordinates. The syntax is `line([x1 x2 x3 ...], [y1 y2 y3 ...])`, so when you write `line([1 1], [300 800])` you are drawing a line from `(1,300)` to `(1,800)` (just as you later say).

What you seem to be wanting to plot is in this case is `line([1 300], [1 800])`.

Comment: thanks, it worked setting 
    line([l1(ii, 2) l2(ii, 2)], [l1(ii, 1) l2(ii, 1)], ... 
          'Color', color, 'LineWidth', 1)

Comment: The problem was also that a function that I was using switched rows and columns arrays, that's why I used in the fix line([y1 y2 ...], [x1 x2 ...)
thanks again